# jQuery how to code it more nicely

Tags: jquery

How do you make this code shorter, i'm very new to jquery but i managed to build what i wanted, but is there another way to do this e.g more nicely.

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

       $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".genre").click(function () {
       $(".sobox").hide(); 
       $(".fobox").fadeIn() 
       $("#notcurrent").css({"background":"#9aa0ae", "color":"#fefefe"}); 
       $("#current").css({"background":"#2568be", "color":"#fff"}); 

         });

       $(".other").click(function () {
       $(".fobox").hide();  
       $(".sobox").fadeIn();  
       $("#current").css({"background":"#9aa0ae", "color":"#fefefe"}); 
       $("#notcurrent").css({"background":"#2568be", "color":"#fff"}); 

       });
      });

</script>
```

Comment: are you mean how to Reduce size of your js?

Comment: no make it shorter and nicer.

Comment: I think your code is good but way of @rrr in answers is very better and clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any serious issues with your existing code, but you could store the CSS style objects in variables rather than repeating them.

Additionally, **so long as all the elements exist in the DOM at the time your click event handlers are defined**, you could use cached jQuery selectors for a small performance gain.

i.e. assuming in your first event handler you meant to change the style of the `#notcurrent` element and not a different one `#ncurrent`, and that the `fobox/sobox/current/notcurrent` elements exist when the DOM is initially loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function () {
  var styleA = {"background":"#9aa0ae", "color":"#fefefe"},
      styleB = {"background":"#2568be", "color":"#fff"},
      current = $("#current"),
      notCurrent = $("#notcurrent"),
      fobox = $(".fobox"),
      sobox = $(".sobox");

  $(".genre").click(function () {
    sobox.hide(); 
    fobox.fadeIn() 
    notCurrent.css(styleA); 
    current.css(styleB);
  });

  $(".other").click(function () {
    fobox.hide();  
    sobox.fadeIn();  
    current.css(styleA); 
    notCurrent.css(styleB); 
  });
});

</script>
```

Long story short, I don't see a clear way to significantly reduce the size of the code, but there are some ways you could make it a little more efficient while maintaining readability.  Other answers show how you could define a single callback function that may result in less code.

Comment: I think adding classes instead of styles would be an even better improvement (didn't do it for mine, either, though. ;-) ), but keeping a 1:1 mapping of the original poster's technique, I don't think it gets too much better than this. Note to the OP: this isn't fewer lines of code, either. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think your code as is is fine.

But since you've asked, another way to do it would be to define some classes in your stylesheet rather than coding the CSS attributes directly in your JavaScript then you can tidy up your JS somewhat by making use of jQuery's [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) methods:

```
.class1 {
    background:#9aa0ae;
    color:#fefefe;
}

.class2 {
    background : #2568be;
    color : #fff
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".genre, .other").click(function () {
     $(".sobox,.fobox").toggle("fast"); 
     $("#notcurrent,#current").toggleClass("class1 class2");
   });
});
```

You would initially need to assign one or the other of the `sobox` or `fobox` classes to start out as `display:none`, and give the "notcurrent" and "current" elements one each of "class1" and "class2", as shown in this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XghA6/ (And obviously you'd come up with more meaningful class names than my "class1" and "class2"...)

Comment: Its the cleanest and best way of doing it :)

Comment: You can do `$(document).delegate/on` instead of `$(document).ready` to make it shorter and get rid off one level of indentation :P

Comment: @Esailija - True. And/or put the whole script at the bottom of the body to avoid any need for document.ready at all... Not to mention the slightly shorter version of `$(document).ready()` as simply `$()`...

Answer (score 2):

**Formatting wasn't good in comment, so pasting it here.**

I think this code is good. There's nothing wrong in it.
You may try,

```
$(".genre,.other").click(function () {
      if($(this).hasClass('genre')){
         $(".sobox").hide(); 
         $(".fobox").fadeIn() ;
         $("#notcurrent").css({"background":"#9aa0ae", "color":"#fefefe"}); 
         $("#current").css({"background":"#2568be", "color":"#fff"}); 
       }
       else{
         $(".fobox").hide();  
         $(".sobox").fadeIn(); 
         $("#current").css({"background":"#9aa0ae", "color":"#fefefe"}); 
         $("#notcurrent").css({"background":"#2568be", "color":"#fff"}); 
       }   
  });
```

Point it that you can select more than 1 class. And thus do you processing.

Comment: Won't this always set the #current/#ncurrent CSS styles the same way, rather than alternating them?

Comment: @rrr thanks for pointing it out.

DonVitto , as I mentioned, your code is fine, there's nothing wrong in it. I just showed a different way of doing it.

Comment: Code is incorrect. Missing **)**. Plus, **hasClass** returns a boolean, so `if($(this).hasClass('genre'){` should be `if($(this).hasClass('genre') === true){`. But great code.

Comment: @Shawn31313 yes, ')' was missing. I've corrected. But you need not to check if it is true. As you said, hasClass returns a boolean, and 'if' needs a boolean to work; so why double check with == true ?

Comment: I like double check, just for look.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I'd recommend is adding classes rather than modifying css directly through jquery. Beyond that, I don't see anything that looks like it needs refactoring - there isn't much code here to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a loaded question since we can only guess what the intention of the code is. Without recommending a different approach, it's a good idea to cache jQuery objects that are used more than once:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $sobox = $(".sobox"),
    $fobox = $(".fobox"),
    $current = $("#current"),
    $notcurrent = $("#notcurrent");

  $(".genre").click(function () {
    $sobox.hide(); 
    $fobox.fadeIn()      
    $current.css({"background":"#2568be", "color":"#fff"}); 
    $notcurrent.css({"background":"#9aa0ae", "color":"#fefefe"});
  });

  $(".other").click(function () {
    $fobox.hide();  
    $sobox.fadeIn();  
    $current.css({"background":"#9aa0ae", "color":"#fefefe"}); 
    $notcurrent.css({"background":"#2568be", "color":"#fff"}); 
  });
});
```

Note that I personally like using the `$` symbol as part of my variable name to help me remember it's a jQuery object, but you don't have to.

Beyond that, I generally think it's not a good idea to change the appearance of elements by adding css rules directly. Instead, consider using `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` or possibly `.toggleClass()` depending on if it meets your end goals or not.

I also like using event delegation instead of directly binding click events, but if your code doesn't need it (no Ajax or DOM elements being destroyed) then there's no need to bother. But look up `.on()` anyhow so that you can understand event binding in the latest jQuery.

More generally: I would consider creating this as a utility function... without spending time on how that might look like, I can see having the entire contents of the click functions operate as a separate re-usable piece of code. But I admit I didn't really go too deeply into thoughts on how this might be done.

[edit: Jashwant has a good idea, too!]

Comment: this didn't work i think i'll keep mine since the idea behind it was to make it shorter e.g less code. thanks anyways

Comment: Hey Don, it *has* to work (assuming the code you provided works), so you've done something differently. ;-) All I did here was cache the objects you're creating. So there's probably just a typo in it somewhere. Less lines of code is a great goal, and for that I like Jashwant's approach (once the fixes are in). However, 'more nicely' don't always mean fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Typed on ipad, so sorry for any errors ;).  Assuming on load one box is showing and one isnt, you could simplify this down.

First, add two CSS classes.

```
.class1 { background:"#9aa0ae"; color:"#fefefe"; }
.class2 { background:"#2568be"; color:"#fff"; }
```

And for the js, just combine your handlers.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".genre").click(function () {
       $(".sobox, .fobox").fadeToggle(); 
       $("#notcurrent, #current").toggleClass('class1 class2');

     });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `.fadeToggle()` until I read your answer. Note that you can combine the classes to toggle in a single call: `.toggleClass("class1 class2")`.